# Why is getting GPS fix so slow?

Tags: gps

I understand the basic concepts of GPS positioning system and the use of trilateration but I don't understand why it takes so much time to get a fix.

On commercial GPS like TomTom it usually takes about one minute and on my phone it can take more than 5 minutes to be located.

Is it because of the computation time or it needs to collect more data before having a good approximation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [time to first fix (TTFF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix) is dependent on many variables such as the state of the [almanac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Almanac) and [ephemeris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Navigation_message) data on the device, the device's [dilution of precision (DOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) thresholds, the current positions of satellites in the sky and any obstructions, and whether the device is using normal GPS or [assisted GPS (aGPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS) (which theoretically should reduce the TTFF but perhaps there are circumstances where aGPS isn't enough to make up for the quality of the device's GPS functionality).

Answer (score 3):

[pocketgpsworld.com](http://www.pocketgpsworld.com/howgpsworks.php) explains it quite well, might be overkill for your question on a technical level but hopefully you get a better understanding of the process to achieve a fix.

Have an old [Nokia N82](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_n82-2177.php) (GPS receiver at the top of the phone) and will get a cold fix (no assisted GPS etc) in less than 30 secs - new models have been slower since.